# How can I include a coffeescript variable in an interpolated ERB string in a rails helper?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, erb

I would like to include this coffeescript variable (`chordCount`) in the ERB below, but when it runs it has an error because it is trying to interpret chordCount as a ruby variable. How can I use it in the ERB?

`app/views/static_pages/add_chord.js.coffee` (below) is reached via a `remote: true` link. It works perfectly with the one exception mentioned above (e.g. if I replace the variable with "4" then it works fine, but with the variable it throws an error).

```
chordCount = $('.chordSearchForm').find('.chordSearchFieldRow').length

# define the html for the row to add
rowToAdd = "<div class='row chordSearchFieldRow'>" +
    "<div class='large-8 small-12 columns'>" +
    '<%= collection_select :chords, :chord_#{chordCount}, Chord.order("name ASC"), :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => false, class: "chordSearchField", id: "chord_#{chordCount}_search_field" } %>' +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't want to be writing html like this. Use the tag helpers:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

Secondly, for storing variables for use in javascript, it's best to set it in a data attribute.

An example might look like this:

`content_tag(:p, data: { chord_count: chordCount })`

which would make it available in your js by

```
$("p").data("chord_count")
```

if your using jquery.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please show an example of using that stored data within a rails helper (like above)? The problem I am having is using the variable within the rails helper. Thanks again

Comment: Uhh? That's usually a good indication of bad design. Javascript is clientside, you can't "use" the variable in ERB, unless you output a script tag, which is also bad.

Comment: This is an x y problem, instead of asking how to access the coffeescript variable in erb, ask how to accomplish what your trying to do. Why do you need to access the variable

Comment: I have 3 collection select fields on a static page. I have an "Add Another Input" link and a "Remove an Input" link so that users can alter the number of links. Each link has a name (e.g. input_1, input_2) and an html ID that follows the same pattern. I need to count the number of inputs on the screen and send this number (+1) to the rails helper method so that it can put in the ID/name for the new input field. What is the best/"railsiest" way to accomplish this? Thanks again